# Compiler Constuction

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, compiler-optimization

I am doing Compiler design and construction. I've been wondering why do we actually need six phases in compilers. could some one please point out some advantages of having a number of phases in compilation process?

Comment: Which phases are you talking about specifically? There are countless slightly different such lists.

Comment: It's a program, ie a way of breaking down a large task into smaller ones...

Comment: Just six? Ridiculous! Should be much, much more than six. See this for inspiration: http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/nano-jfp.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modularity, simply. So when you want to write a compiler for a different language or target machine then you only have to change those modules.

Comment: That does not explain why six.  You only need two (maybe three) for that: the front end changes for a new language, the back end changes for a new target.  (The third is the middle end, which stays the same in both cases.)

Comment: Allow me to quote Andrew W. Appel: 

"Any large software system is much easier to understand and implement if the designer takes care with the fundamental abstractions and interfaces."

Comment: + "Breaking the compiler into this many pieces allows for reuse of the components. For example, to change the target-machine for which the compiler produces machine language, it suffices to replace just the Frame Layout and Instruction Selection modules. To change the source language being compiled, only the modules up through Translate need to be changed.The compiler can be attached to a language-oriented syntax editor at the Abstract Syntax interface."

Answer (score 4):

As delnan says, you should explicitly say which phases you are talking about. They are not so standardized that we know exactly the six you are talking about. A compiler is still an ordinary program, and like ordinary programs, may reflect the style of its authors.

Part of the answer is **because compilation is a hugely difficult problem**. I used to have the exact same question, but for what is probably only considered one phase in the 6-phase scheme you are thinking of: parsing. Why does everyone always first divide the input stream into tokens (lexing), and then only give structure to the sequence of tokens (parsing)? Why do people teach it as if it was the only way? Is there a theorem that says it has to be done this way?

In retrospect, the answer was that there may be other ways to do it, but this one was found to work, and since just the problem of converting linear text into structured ASTs is a hugely difficult one (when considered in abstracto, without the knowledge we have accumulated), any sub-division of the initial problem into well-identified sub-tasks helps. If a particular sub-division worked in the past, why not continue to do it this way?

Of course, parsing is itself only one sub-task in the hugely difficult problem of converting text to executable code. I suspect that the same empirical approach was used at each level of compiler design. The way we do it now reflects the history of past tries at the problem.

Comment: This particular one (lexing, then parsing) is long known as being far from optimal or even reasonable. And, no, compilation is hilariously trivial problem, and it's mostly trivial because it's possible (and easy) to split it into well-separated phases, unlike most other programming problems. Compilers complexity is hugely overrated.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, I know, lexerless vs. traditional parsing is a bit of a holy war, but nevertheless, you have to admit lexerless is getting a much wider acceptance these days.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely possible to write a single-pass compiler. It may not be a good idea, but it is possible, so no, we do not “need” six passes.

As @transporter_room_3 correctly pointed out, having multiple passes (and having those passes work with well-defined interfaces, more often than not by having all intermediary  passes receive and emit the same IR) simply makes it easier to read and therefore to design and write as well as change and maintain the compiler.

As to why exactly six – I don’t think there is any agreement on that number, and there certainly are people who would count each distinct optimization module as a separate pass and therefore would, in their own count, happily change the number of passes frequently. I assume you are currently in a compiler course and your teacher just told you you were using six phases? Well, then there’s your answer: To make learning easier, we usually do not learn/teach the fully general picture right from the beginning. We look at some restricted area first and then later check which of the boundaries are just for learning and which ones are inherent in the problem. Or would you teach a four to six year old about sets and monoids before starting to count?